# Multiple Auto fade in/fade out on loop in multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

I have 3 columns in a table with different pictures in each. I am trying to have the fade at different times with different pictures in a loop and to start automatically.

I have managed to get it working but i have after about 20 seconds i have white boxes and not images.

Here is a link to it on https://jsfiddle.net/nmcj4yze/3/.

My Jquery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
var InfiniteRotator = {
    init: function () {
        //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
        var initialFadeIn = 4000;
        //interval between items (in milliseconds)
        var itemInterval = 4000;
        //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
        var fadeTime = 4000;
        //count number of items
        var numberOfItems = $('.rotating-home').length;
        //set current item
        var currentItem = 0;
        //show first item
        $('.rotating-home').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(initialFadeIn);
        //loop through the items
        var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function () {
            $('.rotating-home').eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (numberOfItems - 1)) + 1;
            currentItem = (currentItem + rand) % numberOfItems;
            $('.rotating-home').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime);
        }, itemInterval);
    }
};
InfiniteRotator.init();
});
//]]>
```

Css:

```
body {
color:#999;
font-family:"MS Serif", "New York", serif;
font-size:16px;
padding-left:20px;}
/* slider */
#rotating-item-wrapper {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
height: 150px;
}
.rotating-home {
display:;
position: absolute;
}
```

And Html:

```
<table width="60%" align="center">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="rotating-home-wrapper">
            <div class="rotating-home">
                <img src="http://paul.cerrone.me/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/BQcDAAAAAwoDanBnAAAABC5vdXQKFjlCVTZ6M0RDM3hHN2xTbFRpWUlPQlEAAAACaWQKAXgAAAAEc2l6ZQ.jpg" height="100" width="100" border="0" />
            </div>
            <div class="rotating-home">
                <img src="http://www.dailyfailcenter.com/sites/default/files/fail/ea662e71d267.jpg" class="slide" height="100" width="100" border="0" />
            </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="rotating-home">
            <img src="http://blog.epromos.com/images/google-dog.jpg" class="slide" height="100" border="0" />
        </div>
        <div class="rotating-home">
            <img src="http://www.thelastnewspaper.com/images-future/gps-dog-tracking-300x400.jpg" class="slide" height="100" border="0" />
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="rotating-home">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQHzIZUSCKJBajh8kY8zbVmyYYBCbzgy7ADISw6h9cCJ-Mw2pwnFw" class="slide" height="100" border="0" />
        </div>
        <div class="rotating-home">
            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSWgFW9ZbKPn3_ECEJgV58atYzlbyZzKzvkhgsP3zdt4BFmw_7GfQ" class="slide" height="100" border="0" />
        </div>
    </td>
    </div>
</tr>
```

**Updated**

Sorry i should of been more clear. 
At first i want 3 columns in a table. The first one was 600x600, the second was 300x600 and the third was 300x600. When the page loads  you see 3 pictures. After 4 seconds column 1 fades into another picture without going to a white background. After another 4 seconds column two fades into a another picture, and after another 4 seconds column 3 does then same. I would like to  be on a continuous cycle so it would start again. But i couldn't do that, i did achieve something close with a random cycle but i have white backgrounds after about  20 seconds. Not sure where i am going wrong

I have tried everything and and look everywhere.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: please explain more, what do you want in output ?

Comment: Sorry i should of been more clear. At first i want 3 columns in a table. The first one was 600x600, the second was 300x600 and the third was 300x600. When the page loads  you see 3 pictures. After 4 seconds column 1 fades into another picture without going to a white background. After another 4 seconds column two fades into a another picture, and after another 4 seconds column 3 does then same. I would like to  be on a continuous cycle so it would start again. But i couldn't do that, i did achieve something close with a random cycle but i have white backgrounds after about  20 seconds. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the following is what you wanted:

https://jsfiddle.net/nmcj4yze/7/

You were on the right track. I cleaned up your HTML a bit, and removed some CSS that wasn't doing anything. I also made it so that the initial image in each table was hidden.

With regards to the javascript, I switched out the selectors to iterate over each `<td>` element, and had it use jQuery's `fadeToggle()` function on its contents. Given that the first item was hidden by default, this would immediately toggle the animations for both images.

Changed your code to the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var InfiniteRotator = {
        init: function () {
            //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
            var initialFadeIn = 4000;
            //interval between items (in milliseconds)
            var itemInterval = 4000;
            //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
            var fadeTime = 4000;
            //count number of items
            var rotationLimit = $('td').length + 1;
            //set current item
            var currentItem = 0;
            //loop through the items
            var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function () {
                $('td').eq(currentItem).find('.rotating-home').fadeToggle(fadeTime);
                currentItem++;
                if(currentItem == rotationLimit) currentItem = 0;
            }, itemInterval);
        }
    };
    InfiniteRotator.init();
});
//]]>
```

```css
@charset"utf-8";
 #page {
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}
body {
    color:#999;
    font-family:"MS Serif", "New York", serif;
    font-size:16px;
    padding-left:20px;
}
.rotating-home {
    position: absolute;
}
.rotating-home:first-of-type {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="60%" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="rotating-home" data-display="0">
                <img src="http://paul.cerrone.me/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/BQcDAAAAAwoDanBnAAAABC5vdXQKFjlCVTZ6M0RDM3hHN2xTbFRpWUlPQlEAAAACaWQKAXgAAAAEc2l6ZQ.jpg" height="100" width="100" border="0" />
            </div>
            <div class="rotating-home" data-display="1">
                <img src="http://www.dailyfailcenter.com/sites/default/files/fail/ea662e71d267.jpg" class="slide" height="100" width="100" border="0" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="rotating-home" data-display="2">
                <img src="http://blog.epromos.com/images/google-dog.jpg" class="slide" height="100" border="0" />
            </div>
            <div class="rotating-home" data-display="3">
                <img src="http://www.thelastnewspaper.com/images-future/gps-dog-tracking-300x400.jpg" class="slide" height="100" border="0" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="rotating-home" data-display="4">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQHzIZUSCKJBajh8kY8zbVmyYYBCbzgy7ADISw6h9cCJ-Mw2pwnFw" class="slide" height="100" border="0" />
            </div>
            <div class="rotating-home" data-display="5">
                <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSWgFW9ZbKPn3_ECEJgV58atYzlbyZzKzvkhgsP3zdt4BFmw_7GfQ" class="slide" height="100" border="0" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention: the `data-display` attributes that I added are not actually relevant. I was planning on using them, but then decided that it wasn't necessary, since you can just use `fadeToggle()` on all child elements of the `<td>`. Didn't think it was worth editing the answer to remove them though.

Comment: Your a genius. Thank you so much. If i had more images in the <td> i can just change  //count number of items
            var rotationLimit = $('td').length + 1;. For example if i had 4 images in each <td> it would be  //count number of items
            var rotationLimit = $('td').length + 4;??

Comment: @GlennMcshane no, that's not how you'd do it. The `rotationLimit` variable is for the number of `<td>` elements, _not_ for the number of images within it. If you wanted more images, I suggest you look into lazy-loading additional images, but stick with the starting 2.